# How to make footer stick to bottom

Tags: html, css

Trying to make the footer in my html css website stick down but nothing works. I've tried changing the position to absolute and fixed and setting bottom: 0 and doing everything but nothing works. Also, is there a better way to make my logo aligned in the middle? Heres my css:

```
.footer{
    background-color: #d62929;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%vw;
    display:block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    min-height: 100%vw;
    }
.contact{
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:block;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 50px;
    }
.info{
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: 30px;
    display:block;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 50px;
    }
.account{
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: 30px;
    display:block;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 50px;

    }
a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color: black;
    font-family: times new roman;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    }
ul{
    list-style: none;
    text-align: left;
    }
.logo_footer{
    float: left;
    padding: 40px 0;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    }
h1{
    color: white;
    font-size: 24;
    }
li{
padding: 5px;
    }
```

Heres my html for the footer:

```
<div>
    <footer class="footer">
           <a href="home"><img src="{{url_for('static', filename='Logo.png')}}" style="height:108px;width:100px;" class="logo_footer" alt="logo"></a></a>
        <div class="contact">
            <h1>Contact us</h1>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Facebook</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Instagram</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Telegram</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="info">
            <h1>Information</h1>
            <ul>
           <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
           <li> <a href="contact_us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Return Policy</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Delivery</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
                <div class="account">
            <h1>Account</h1>
            <ul>
           <li><a href="login.html">Log in</a></li>
           <li> <a href="register.html">Register</a></li>
           <li><a href="#"> My cart</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Please also post your HTML so we can see the layout.

Comment: Can you provide your whole code here

Answer (score 1):

You can make position:fixed; instead of position:absolute; This will make it fixed to the bottom. if there are any other div or something that's causing an overlay issue, use z-index:5;

Comment: maybe he doesn't want a footer to be fixed, maybe he wants something like keeping footer at the bottom of the page, in spite of content before it

Comment: in that case, can't he give a basic min with 100 vh to body ?

Answer (score 0):

I used `postion:relative` on wrapper div and `postion: sticky` on footer.

```css
.sectionWrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.header {
  height: 10vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}
.body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.footer {
  height: 20vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0%;
}
```

```html
<div class="sectionWrapper">
  <section class="header">Header</section>
  <section class="body">Body 1</section>
  <section class="body">Body 2</section>
  <section class="body">Body 3</section>
  <section class="footer">footer</section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways for that.

1. Min-height:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}
.footer {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
```

2. Margin-top, here you do need to specify footer height:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html,
body,
.footer {
    height: 100%;
}
.footer__content {
    box-sizing: border-box;
```

3. This the best, because the height of the footer doesn't matter:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}
.footer {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
```

4. This way is a bit different from others because it uses CSS `calc()` function, and you need to know exact footer height:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.footer__content {
    min-height: calc(100vh - 80px);
}
```

5. This is the most correct way, however it works only in modern browsers, as in the 3rd example, the height doesn't matter:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}
.footer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my project, I am using this to solve same task, it's the easiest solution that I found in Internet:

```
body {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

Here is important to use `min-height` property in body and **not** the `height` one, because actual height of your page can be more that user's screen size.

This solution makes your footer to snap not to screen bottom, but to page bottom.